# Why, when I pass an entity via generic, are attributes duplicated and not what is needed is stored in the database?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a `NestedSetBuilder` class. It has a `MakeRootAsync` method:

```
public async Task<TEntity> MakeRootAsync<TEntity>(TEntity ownerNode) where TEntity: NestedSetEntity
{
    _operation = OperationMakeRoot;
    ownerNode.Lft = 1;
    ownerNode.Rgt = 2;
    ownerNode.Depth = 0;
    await _db.Set<TEntity>().AddAsync(ownerNode);
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return ownerNode;
}
```

There is a base class `NestedSetEntity`:

```
public class NestedSetEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Lft { get; set; }
    public int Rgt { get; set; }
    public int Depth { get; set; }
    public Guid? Tree { get; set; }
}
```

There is a child class `Category`:

```
[Table("categories")]
public class Category: NestedSetEntity
{
    public Category()
    {
        Visible = true;
        CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
        UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [Column("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    [Column("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Column("lft")]
    public int Lft { get; set; }

    [Column("rgt")]
    public int Rgt { get; set; }

    [Column("depth")]
    public int Depth { get; set; }

    [Column("tree")]
    public Guid? Tree { get; set; }

    [Column("visible")]
    public bool Visible { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("created_at")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [Column("updated_at")]
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

There is a method where `makeRootAsync` is called

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Categories()
{
    //var res = await _dnsParserService.ParseCategoriesAsync();
    var res = await _categoryParserService.ParseCategoryListAsync();

    var categoryIds = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var categoryListResItem in res)
    {
        if (categoryIds.TryGetValue(categoryListResItem.CategoryFirstTitle, out var parentCategory)) 
            continue;

        var node = Map(categoryListResItem, "CategoryFirstTitle");
        var addedCategory = await _nestedSetBuilder.MakeRootAsync(node); // this call
        categoryIds[categoryListResItem.CategoryFirstTitle] = addedCategory.Id.ToString();
    }

    return Ok(res);
}
```

In the database, columns `Lft`, `Rgt`, `Depth` have values of zero:

[image]

In the debugger, you can see that the fields are duplicated (separately, the fields of the base class and child class):

[image]

Tell me how to fix it? I use the base class to work with LINQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to the fact that the properties in your derived class [hide the properties in your base class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier). Based on what you need, I'd recommend setting the `Column` attributes on your base class, and remove the derived class properties:

```cs
public class NestedSetEntity
{
    [Column("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Column("lft")]
    public int Lft { get; set; }

    [Column("rgt")]
    public int Rgt { get; set; }

    [Column("depth")]
    public int Depth { get; set; }

    [Column("tree")]
    public Guid? Tree { get; set; }
}

[Table("categories")]
public class Category: NestedSetEntity
{
    public Category()
    {
        Visible = true;
        CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
        UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    [Column("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Column("visible")]
    public bool Visible { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("created_at")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [Column("updated_at")]
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

If you need different column names for the different tables that inherit from `NestedSetEntity`, you can use an interface rather than a base class:

```cs
public interface NestedSetEntity
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    int Lft { get; set; }
}

[Table("categories")]
public class Category : NestedSetEntity
{
    [Required]
    [Column("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Column("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Column("lft")]
    public int Lft { get; set; }
}

[Table("mytable")]
public class MyTable : NestedSetEntity
{
    [Column("my_id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Column("left_column")]
    public int Lft { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How I can use Interface for EntityClass, if a can declare only methods in interface?

Comment: Interfaces can contain methods, properties, events, indexers, or any combination of those four member types. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the code where `NestedSetEntity` is an interface.